# How to group dataframe rows and perform an operation on rows of every group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

One obvious (and inefficient) approach is to collect group ids and iterate over them:

```
vals = df.groupBy('SomeField').agg(F.count("*").alias("Count")).collect()
for val in vals:
    group_df = df.where(df.SomeField == val.SomeField)
    do_something(group_df)
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: can you show input and output dataframe ? you can also use where fonction on dataframe ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing within `do_something` there are different ways of answering this.

One straightforward answer would be to make do_something a User Defined Function ([UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html)).

You could then have the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

# assuming you are returning an integer
udf_do_something = udf(do_something, IntegerType())

df.groupBy('SomeField').agg(udf_do_something(some_param_1, some_param_2))
```

`some_param_id` would depend on the necessary parameters you need to perform your task in `do_something`. For instance, if you want to process a list of values from a given column, you could use [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html?highlight=collect_list#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list), or even combine it with additional spark sql functions like `when`.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.pivot_table` is probably what you're looking for.

`pd.pivot_table(df, index=[some_fields], values=[other_fields], aggfunc=np.mean)` or some other function